# Sunspot solr index search and index on range data

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I am storing availability timing for my users where they enter for each day of week what timings they would be available

for example - Mr X would be available on

1. sunday for 2-5, 8-12, 15-18
2. monday for 1-3, 5-8, 10-12
3. and so on entire week

what would be the best possible way of indexing and searching this data in solr

a database query for searching such a dataset would be like

```
select * from schedule inner join days on schedule.day_id = days.id 
where days.name = 'Sunday' and schedule.start>=5 and schedule.end>=8
```

Comment: What is your search conditions? And expected result?

Comment: @EricWang updated question with alike database query for search

Answer (score 0):

Use [the `DateRangeField` which became available in Solr5](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates). This allows you to query for documents that contain ranges that matches your query time.

```
fq={!field f=dateRange op=Contains}[2013 TO 2018]
```

Before Solr 5 there's [a neat hack that uses the spatial support](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialForTimeDurations) in Solr to query for overlapping durations (if this point is contained within the expected time area, etc.).

Depending on the needed resolution, you could also index seven different fields (monday - sunday) and then index an integer for each hour that the person is available. You can then query the field with a regular query, such as `available_sunday:15` to find matching persons.